# Undefined variable: products in @foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I am trying to override a view of voyager-admin and edit it but I get an "Undefined variable: products" error and I can't figure out why. 
Here is my OrdersController:

```
$order = Orders::find($id);
$products = $order->products;

return Voyager::view($view, compact('dataType', 'dataTypeContent', 'isModelTranslatable','order', 'products'))
```

Here is my view:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($products as $product)
    <li style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <div>ID Produs: {{$product->id}}</div>
    <div>Nume Produs: {{$product->name}}</div>
    <div>Pret Produs: {{$product->presentPrice()}}</div>
    <div>Cantitate: {{$product->pivot->quantity}}</div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
 </ul>
```

If anything more needed please let me know, I just can't understand why is throwing me this error.

My Orders Model

```
 public function products(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

My Products Model

```
 public function orders(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orders');
}
```

Comment: `return` sounds like that previous code is in a function, is that correct?

Comment: It looks like it should work. You could always skip it and iterate through `$orders->products` instead, if `$orders` works in your view.

Comment: yes it is in the show function of voyager-admin.

Comment: tried with $orders->products and still not working

Comment: What happens with `$orders->products`? Is it complaining that `$orders` is not defined, or that it can't iterate through it?

Comment: Try with dd($orders) to make sure what relationships it brings

Comment: where exactly do I have to do the dd($orders), I am new to laravel. I tried some different options but it doesn't show me the array so I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I did the $order->products in the foreach loop and now it says that $order is not defined

Comment: with dd($order) it gives me that order is not defined.

Comment: double check your product and order relation, did you write something on model to map them(eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

Add validation to check your collectio

```
$order = Orders::find($id);
if($order != null){
$products = $order->products;

return Voyager::view($view, compact('dataType', 'dataTypeContent', 'isModelTranslatable','order', 'products'))
} else {
return null;
}
```

Comment: same result, products is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to override the controller in the Voyager-Admin.